# How can I mix three for-loops? [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

**first loop:**
This loop generates word lists that need to be up to date.

```
for text in current_word:
    current_word_text = text.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    current_word_truncated = current_word_text.replace('_', '')
    current_word_length = len(current_word_text)
    current_word_truncated_list = list(current_word_truncated)
    current_word_letter_position = current_word_text.index(
       current_word_truncated) + 1
    words_length_list = [word for word in temp if len(
       word) == current_word_length]

    words_letter_list = [
       word for word in words_length_list if current_word_truncated in word]
    if '_' in current_word_text:
       third_list = [word for word in words_length_list if all(
            letter in word.lower() for letter in current_word_truncated_list)]
       print(third_list)
```

**second loop:**
This loop uses selenium chrome webdriver to write words from the word lists above into a textarea for a certain period of time.

```
timer = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="timer"]')
for txt in timer:
   for item in third_list:
       third_list = [word for word in words_length_list if all(
            letter in word.lower() for letter in current_word_truncated_list)]
       print(third_list)
       text_input.send_keys(item)
       time.sleep(1)
       text_input.send_keys(u'\ue007')
       timer_text = txt.get_attribute('innerHTML')
       if int(timer_text) == 80:
           break
   timer_text = txt.get_attribute('innerHTML')
   if int(timer_text) == 80:
       break
```

During the second loop, the word lists from above should always be updated. That's why I want to mix both loops so that the current words are written in the textarea.